# What types of literals does Javascript support?

Tags: javascript, literals

Perhaps this seems like a silly question, but I ask because I just learned about regular expression literals:

```
var foo = /ba+r/s;
```

which is equivalent to

```
var foo = new RegExp('ba+r', 's');
```

Which got me thinking, what other literals does Javascript support? The documentation at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

mentions string, array, object, and number literals, but it does not mention function or regular expression literals.

What is the complete list of Javascript literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ECMAScript 5, this is defined in Section 7.8:

[**7.8 - Literals**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8) (*Literal*)

- [7.8.1 - Null Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.1) (*NullLiteral*)
- [7.8.2 - Boolean Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.2) (*BooleanLiteral*)
- [7.8.3 - Numeric Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) (*NumericLiteral*)
- [7.8.4 - String Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4) (*StringLiteral*)
- [7.8.5 - Regular Expression Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5) (*RegularExpressionLiteral*)

Apart from those, there are also initialisers, which are similar to literals:

- [11.1.4 - Array Initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) (*ArrayLiteral*)

  > An array initialiser is an expression describing the initialisation of
  >   an Array object, written in a form of a literal.
- [11.1.5 - Object Initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) (*ObjectLiteral*)

  > An object initialiser is an expression describing the initialisation
  >   of an Object, written in a form resembling a literal.

Comment: Thanks, Oriol. Am to understand that "function literal" is a misnomer?

Comment: @petehern I can't find any reference of "function literal" in the spec, and I have never heard it. Maybe you mean ["function expression" or "function declaration"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13)?

Comment: You will sometimes see unnamed functions, eg `var foo = function() {alert("hello");}` called a function literal. Is this incorrect nomenclature? (i.e. An unamed function isn't a literal?)

Comment: @petehern I would call them "anonymous functions" (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), "function literal" is a synonym). ECMAScript 5 spec doesn't define neither of those terms, but ECMAScript 6 draft uses "[anonymous function](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-name)".